# Can C# .NET Upload Files to an FTPS Server Running pure-ftpd Requiring Explicit FTP over TLS?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftps, pureftpd

When trying to upload a file to an ftp server running pure-ftpd (configured for FTPS *not* SFTP, requiring explicit FTP over TLS) via .NET an exception is thrown:

> `Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation`.

Server logs appear to indicate everything going well up until the client stops communicating after a `150 Accepted data connection` log message.

Client logs indicate that bytes were written to the stream but closing the stream seems to trigger the exception.

A file *is* created on the ftp server; however, no content is written to it.

Other clients (i.e. Filezilla) work to upload files (using the same credentials, from the same network/machine to the same server) without issue.

Other similar problems I've seen suggest changing the various properties of the request (`EnableSsl`, `UseBinary`, `UsePassive`, `KeepAlive`, `Timeout`).  I've tried various combinations of these properties, but to no avail.

I'm at a loss as to what the problem is .  I'm inclined to believe it's a client-side misconfiguration as other languages/clients connect to the server without issue. I don't call myself a C#/.NET developer, so there may be something obvious that I'm missing - any help is appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

Uri target = new Uri("ftp://ftp.example.com:21/filenamehere");
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(target);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.EnableSsl = true;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "password");
request.UseBinary = true;
request.UsePassive = true;
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Timeout = -1;

Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"testfile.txt");
Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
int read;
while ((read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    Console.WriteLine("Uploaded {0} bytes", fileStream.Position);
}

ftpStream.Close();
Console.WriteLine("done...");
```

client output:

```
Uploaded 10240 bytes
Uploaded 20480 bytes
Uploaded 30720 bytes
Uploaded 40960 bytes
Uploaded 51200 bytes
Uploaded 61440 bytes
Uploaded 71680 bytes
Uploaded 81920 bytes
Uploaded 92160 bytes
Uploaded 92295 bytes
```

> Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation
> at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
> at System.Net.CommandStream.InvokeRequestCallback(Object obj)
> at System.Net.CommandStream.Abort(Exception e)
> at System.Net.CommandStream.CheckContinuePipeline()
> at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.DataStreamClosed(CloseExState closeState)
> at System.Net.FtpDataStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
> at System.Net.FtpDataStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
> at System.IO.Stream.Close()
> at Program.$(String[] args) in /Users/user/MyApp/Program.cs:line 27

server output:

```
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (?@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] Command [user] [myusername]
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (?@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] 331 User myusername OK. Password required
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.info pure-ftpd: (?@XX.XX.XX.XX) [INFO] myusername is now logged in
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] Command [pbsz] [0]
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] 200 PBSZ=0
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] Command [prot] [P]
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] 200 Data protection level set to "private"
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] Command [opts] [utf8 on]
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] 500 Unknown command
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] Command [pwd] []
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] 257 "/" is your current location
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] Command [type] [I]
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] Command [pasv] []
Jan  6 23:46:06 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] 227 Entering Passive Mode (YY,YY,YY,YY,YY,YY)
Jan  6 23:46:07 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] Command [stor] [filenamehere]
Jan  6 23:46:07 machine1 ftp.debug pure-ftpd: (myusername@XX.XX.XX.XX) [DEBUG] 150 Accepted data connection
```

Answer (score 0):

While I can't pinpoint with absolute certainty the cause of the issue prompting this question, it appears a .NET update on/around 2019-10 is the culprit.  Updating pureftpd to a newer version (at least 1.0.49-r2) appears to  make pureftpd play nicer with the updated version of .NET.

Thanks to @Martin Prikryl for the linked question (specifically the references in the answer).